# Can I switch IMG src when clicking the parent container div?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, events, click

This question is in a way a follow up of my earlier questions. Right now I have two sibling classes in html, inside another container div:

```
 <div class="containertira">
    <img id="primeiraimagem" class="imgclasstosize" src="img/Tiras/11 - Mora.png">
    <div class="centered">Mora</div>
 </div>
```

When I click the container the `imgclasstosize` img expands to a bigger format, and the the div `centered` disappears. Everything returns to their initial values if I click another `containertira`. I hope i'm explaining this correctly.
Right now the JS i have is this:

```
const allImages = document.querySelectorAll('.imgclasstosize');
allImages.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      const thisImg = event.target;
      const sibling = thisImg.nextElementSibling; // Get the next sibiling
      sibling.classList.toggle("hide"); // Add class to the current sibling

      const allOtherImages = Array.from(allImages).filter(img => {
        return img !== thisImg;
      });
      allOtherImages.forEach(img => {
        img.classList.remove('big')
        sibling.classList.add("hide"); // Add hide class to other image siblings
      });
      thisImg.classList.toggle('big');


    });
  }

);
```

So my question is, is it possible to change the src of the image inside `imgclasstosize` when the container is clicked, and then have it return to normal when clicked again or another container is clicked (like the behaviour of the image enlargement)?

Best wishes to you all,
JM

Comment: use an onclick event on the contaienr or add an eventlistener that listen to clicks on the contaienr and then trigger the script.

Comment: Instead of toggling or adding classes, call `.setAttribute("src", url)` on the image. If you need to keep track of stuff, note that you can always use `el.dataset.myVar = x;` for that (and read back the value).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, and with surprisingly few modifications to your code; see `***` comments:

```
// *** Hook `click` on the containers
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.containertira');
containers.forEach(container => {
    container.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        // *** Find the image within this container -- note using `this` (or `event.currentTarget`),
        // not `event.target`
        const thisImg = this.querySelector(".imgclasstosize");
        const sibling = thisImg.nextElementSibling; // Get the next sibiling
        sibling.classList.toggle("hide"); // Add class to the current sibling
  
        // *** Find the other images here
        const allOtherImages = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".imgclasstosize")).filter(img => {
            return img !== thisImg;
        });
        allOtherImages.forEach(img => {
            img.classList.remove('big')
            sibling.classList.add("hide"); // Add hide class to other image siblings
        });
        thisImg.classList.toggle('big');
    });
  }
);
```

There are other things you could probably do to the code as well (or not, depending on your preference and the greater context), but that should get you going the right way.

For instance, you could even probably do this by using event delegation on whatever container contains all the containers (`body` in the worst case) rather than an separate handler on each element.

It may also be possible to find the other elements by doing `document.querySelectorAll(".imgclasstosize.big")` (rather than creating an array and `filter`ing it), assuming that the current image doesn't have the class...

Answer (score 0):

I took a bit too long with my answer, so you already got a good explanation. But as I already had prepared a fully working example, I didn't want to let that go to waste and decided to post it anyway:

```js
const allImages = document.querySelectorAll('.containertira .imgclasstosize');
const allContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.containertira');
allContainers.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      const thisImg = el.querySelector('.imgclasstosize');
      const sibling = thisImg.nextElementSibling; // Get the next sibiling
      const bigSrc = thisImg.dataset.srcBig;

      const allOtherImages = Array.from(allImages).filter(img => {
        return img !== thisImg;
      });
      
      const isBig = thisImg.classList.contains('big');1
      
      if( isBig ) {
        thisImg.classList.remove('big');
        // reset to the small image URL
        thisImg.src = thisImg.dataset.smallSrc;
      } else {
        // save the small image URL first:
        if ( !thisImg.dataset.smallSrc ) {
          thisImg.dataset.smallSrc = thisImg.src;
        }
        // change to the big image URL:
        thisImg.src = bigSrc;
        thisImg.classList.add('big');
        sibling.classList.remove('hide');
      }
      
      allOtherImages.forEach(img => {
        img.classList.remove('big');
        // reset to the small image URL
        if ( img.dataset.smallSrc ) {
          img.src = img.dataset.smallSrc;
        }
        img.nextElementSibling.classList[ isBig ? 'remove' : 'add']("hide");
      });
    });
  }

);
```

```css
.containertira { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
.hide { display: none; }
.imgclasstosize { width: 60px; }
.big { width: 120px; }
.centered { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div class="containertira">
  <img id="primeiraimagem" class="imgclasstosize" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/60/60" data-src-big="https://picsum.photos/id/237/120/120">
  <div class="centered">foo</div>
</div>

<div class="containertira">
  <img id="secondimage" class="imgclasstosize" src="https://picsum.photos/id/248/60/60" data-src-big="https://picsum.photos/id/248/120/120">
  <div class="centered">bar</div>
</div>

<div class="containertira">
  <img id="thirdimage" class="imgclasstosize" src="https://picsum.photos/id/348/60/60" data-src-big="https://picsum.photos/id/348/120/120">
  <div class="centered">baz</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry as for I am pretty noob and new to this coding thing, but I don't understand something. This isn't changing the src of the image right? This is only adding and removing to the img class and it's sibling. That class only does the image enlargement but does not change the URL src of the said clicked IMG. Am I correct?

Comment: Right, currently there's no change of the src. But you should be able to add that where currently only the class changes take place

Comment: But wouldn't that be a class wide change? That wouldn't be ID specific right? Is the only solution to change individual urls, to make ID specific function?

Comment: I updated the example code to implement what you're trying to achieve. This uses a custom data-attribute to specify the URL for the large image

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I set out to do, but somewhere along the updated code you lost the ability to hide the sibling div of the "imgclasstosize", namely the class "centered"